# Curl error 7 when installing apps on nextcloud

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-20.04, nextcloud

Hey this is my first question on here, so go easy.

I set up a Nextcloud server on my homelab in an ubuntu server 20.04 vm using the snap install. I have a seperate vm running nginx as a reverse proxy to my Nextcloud instance. Everything works flawlessly as intended, except that when I try and install apps on Nextcloud, I get a curl error #7. I've tried using my lan ip through the web ui, my public domain name through the web ui, and the commandline using the nextcloud.occ app:install command. I always get the same error. I tried to find the appropriate log file to get more information but looking in /var/snap/nextcloud/current/log/ I couldn't find any relevant info in any of the logs. Running php -m comes up with php not installed, I guess because php is installed via the Nextcloud snap? Obviously php is installed somewhere because Nextcloud is running, but I don't know how to look and see what modules are enabled, or how to install new ones using the snap. Any help on what to do is much appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpc3q.png)

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed it. I think I had improperly configured my firewall, and turning it off (in proxmox)/making some changes to my /etc/netplan/*.yaml file to properly configure the static IP fixed it. GL

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be a wrongliy configured network. I forgot to set the gateway/proxy for IPv4, so github.com was unreachable. Most other services I use seem to resolve IPv6 first, so I did not have any other problems besides updating nextcloud apps.